# Maximum Likelihood Estimation: Transformation from Product-Of-Likelihoods to Sum-Of-Log-Likelihoods

Tags: maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I'm reading the [Deep Learning Book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville. I'm struggling to follow an argument in [Chapter 5.5](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) (pages 129-130);

[image: Except from Ch 5.5 in the Deep Learning Book]

How do they make the jump from equation 5.57 to 5.58? Have they implicitly taken a log of the result of the product, allowing them to use the log product expansion rule? I.e.

$$\log (ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$$

Or is this a special case where the argmax allows for this transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the log of the product gives the sum of log
$$\log (xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$$
This is true since log is increasing function